# Operations based on user input Swift

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift, nsstring, ios8, xcode6

long question, so bear with me...

I am attempting to create a bitcoin ticker and converter written in Swift. I am using the code below (bits not related to conversion are removed - let me know if I left out anything important)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var USD: UITextField! //Amount of USD. Originally equals 1 bitcoin, can be changed by user.
     @IBOutlet weak var BTC: UILabel! //Amount of bitcoins the entered amount of USD is worth. Originally 1.

    func handler(response: NSURLResponse!, data : NSData!, error : NSError!) { //To fetch Bitcoin Price. This is functional.

      if ((error) != nil) {
            self.USD.text = "No Internet" // in case of error
      } else {
            var price = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            self.USD.text = price //set USD to be equal to price of 1 Bitcoin

      }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            //Sets up view
            self.update() //Fetches Bitcoin Price. This works.
            self.convert() //Begins convert method
            var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(120, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
   }

   func convert() {
            var url = NSURL(string:"https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/USD/last")
            var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:handler)

            var data = NSData(contentsOfURL:url);
            while true {
                 if USD.text != data {
                 BTC.text = USD.text /  NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)// Attempts to determine amount of bitcoin the USD amount is worth. ERROR HERE!
            }

    }
```

On the line with the comment "ERROR HERE", I get the error

`/Users/[My User]/Documents/dev/Newest Stuff/CryptoCoinTicker/CryptoCoinTicker/ViewController.swift:95:32: 'String' is not convertible to 'UInt8'`

In case the code doesn't tell the story, I want BTC.text to change to be equal in value to the amount entered by the user in USD.text (so if a bitcoin is worth $500, and the user entered 250.00, BTC.text would say 0.5.

What do I need to do? Apologies for a (probably) basic question, I am but a newbie. Let me know if you ned more info.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get that error, it usually means that you are trying to assign a wrong type to a variable or that you are using the wrong types for function parameters.
In your case, you are trying to divide two Strings. The compiler doesn't know what to do, since the division of Strings is not defined. You can only divide Int, Float and Double and you can't even mix them!

So for that line you can substitute this:

```
let value = NSString(string: USD.text).doubleValue / NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding).doubleValue
BTC.text = "\(value)"
```

This first "converts" the USD.text to NSString and then converts both NSStrings to Doubles, which you can then divide.
It then creates a String from that value, which can be assigned to the BTC.text property.